# unable to find the namespace of a third party api

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have received a .dll file from a partner firm with an API that will be used for database logging. I have added it to the references and can see it in the Solution Explorer. The documentation provided gave me a code snippet which references the file with a different namespace than the file name. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express.

```
using com.XXXXX.XXX.microsites.api;
```

When I want to use the EntityFramework, it is simply the name of the reference.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

- The reference is not even showing up with a different name when using IntelliSense.
- I am using the recommend framework ASP.NET 4 in the documentation.
- I am using the code snippet they provided.

Comment: make sure you are using same .net version with .dll file

Comment: I am a little confused with your question. Did you try the snippet they gave you? The namespace does not have to match the dll name. They may have renamed the dll for some reason but since they published the API they left the namespace the same,

Comment: I am using the recommend framework ASP.NET 4 in the documentation.
I am using the code snippet they provided.

Comment: Do they expose their API through COM? Can you register the dll with either regvr32 or regasm? Do their instructions say anything about adding the reference as a COM reference?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use dotPeek (https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile the assembly and see what the defined namespaces are. Not sure if there's anything build in to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the dll reference in your solution then try opening the dll in `object browser` and see if you see the namespaces listed there and then use the one needed.

Comment: It doesn`t display any namespaces.

Comment: Namespace need not be similar to dll name. You said that, you have got a documentation, see what's the namespace getting used there.